# ArrayList (completely deep copy)

Tags: java, arraylist, clone, deep-copy, copyonwritearraylist

Before entering question, I know other than primitive type, everything is stored by its reference number. My java code structure is something like this..... First I have driver, reservation and car classes. The relationship between them is driver is a driver who performed reservation and car is booked up to be driven that is stored in reservation class.

Driver will take care of reservation. Cars have a few primitive types information. Multiple cars can be stored into the reservation (primitive and `ArrayList`). But one driver (`ArrayList`) (from driver class) can have multiple reservations. So, when I allow users to view what driver has in his reservations, I would like to deep copy everything in the `ArrayList` since everything except for primitive types are reference numbers.

Anyway, I will make a copy of array list for reservation in driver class.

In my driver class, and this is a accessor and when it is passing the `ArrayList`, I attempted to deep copy first and pass the `ArrayList`.

```
public ArrayList<Reference> getReference() {    

    copiedRef = new ArrayList<Reference>();

    //references have been declared above
    for (int i = 0; i < references.size(); i++) {
        copiedRef.add(references.get(i));
        //getting each element in the arrayList one by one and push to a new ArrayList
    }

    return copiedRef;
}
```

Is this doing deep copy? And if I need to use `clone()`.

How would I improve? (`clone` does shallow copy, I don't think `clone` can help for deep copy or I could misunderstand other posts).

Comment: this is a shallow copy. what does your Reference class contain?

Answer (score 3):

Your code achieves no copying at all, except for the list of references. It is equivalent to the one-liner

```
copiedRef = new ArrayList<>(references);
```

`clone` *can* do deep copying, and it is designed specifically to support that. Only the default implementation in `Object` does shallow copying.

However, it is usually not recommended to bother with `clone` due to its arcane contract requirements and limitations with respect to `final` fields. You can instead provide a copy constructor of your domain class.

Usually the simplest way, involving the least code, to achieve deep copying is through in-memory serialize-deserialize cycle. Only note that in this case, "performance" is a dirty word :)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.

```
copiedRef.add(references.get(i));
```

Above code gets each object of type Reference, and stores that references into this new arraylist(copied Ref). You basically need to create a new instance with the same state as each references.get(i) object.

If your Reference type has all the primitive type, you can call `(Reference)references.get(i).clone()` while adding these references.